# Swing Progress Bar updates via Worker to EventDispatch thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, progress-bar, java-6

I have a **JAVA6** GUI handling data import to our database. I have implemented a working JProgressBar. I understand that changes made to the GUI must be done via the event dispatch thread--which I do not think I am doing (properly/at all).

the background Worker thread, UploadWorker, is constructed by passing in the a JProgressBar created in the main program, and sets  changes the value of the progress bar directly once it is finished:

```
// when constructed, this gets set to the main program's JProgressBar.
JProgressBar progress; 



protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    write("<!-- Import starting at " + getCurrentTime() + " -->\n");
    boolean chunked = false;
    switch (importMethod) {

            //do some importing

    }

    write("<!-- Import attempt completed at " + getCurrentTime() + "-->\n");

    //here changes to the GUI are made
    progress.setMaximum(0);
    progress.setIndeterminate(false);
    progress.setString("Finished Working");
    return null;
}
```

This works fine, but sometimes(not always) throws me several NPE's in the std out, and users are complaining:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.updateSizes(Unknown Source)
...etc...
```

Anyway, I believe there is something I need to do to get these updates executed on the proper thread, correct? How?

Comment: just discovered SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread, very useful and as I suspected returns false.

Comment: Since you're interacting with the  progress bar in the doInBackground method, then I'd say you are certainly violating the single thread rules of Swing

Comment: i always like this [swing worker example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new Runnable that performs GUI updates and invoke it in a GUI thread using SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: From the sounds if it, you are suggesting that the OP create a `Runnable` which performs there long running/blocking operation and call it using `invokeLater`, if so, that would put them in a worst place then they are right now...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Isn't it clear that I suggest creating a Runnable that performes only GUI updates(not computations/blocking operations) and calling it using invokeLater?

Comment: No, otherwise I wouldn't have commented (I've been up since 330am so I my brain might not be interrupting the response quite right) - Besides, `SwingWorker` provides  `publish`/`process` methods for sending updates to the EDT as well as inbuilt progress support and notification via the `PropertyChange` support...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I forgot about publish/process methods. Anyway, my answer seems to be clear for me(but it is about 2:30 am in my timezone, so I cannot be sure about that).

Comment: I actually tried this first, i created a `new Runnable()` for every update to the progress bar. i used `.isEventDispatchThread()` whereever i made changes to it, which returned `true`. however...i would eventually get that NPE output..

Comment: for my purposes, this answer was actually better (or atleast, easier). for some reason trying to link a Jersey `ContainerListener` to a `PropertyChangeListener` was no good. I noticed there was one more spot where I didn't implement invokeLater that I think lead to the NPE--haven't seen it since.

Comment: @tenwest Just beware that this could saturate the EDT with multiple events, causing a degradation in performance

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah....I don't know, the chunk size got taken to 255 bytes after trying to do it your way (I would much prefer it anyway, but something isn't right). This will have to do it for now. Something tells me the `process` method might be better. Thanks for all of your help @MadProgrammer

Comment: @tenwest You have to do what works for you. If you're processing to fast, SwingWorker may not be able to get enough free time to call process or other updates. You could consider using Thread.yield or Thread.sleep to inject a small break in the doBackground method

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you could do this, you could use the `process` method of the `SwingWorker` to also update the progress bar, but for me, this couples your worker to the UI, which isn't always desirable.

A better solution is to take advantage of the `SwingWorker`s progress and `PropertyChange` support, for example....

```
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("state".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker) evt.getSource();
            switch (worker.getState()) {
                case DONE:
                    // Clean up here...
                    break;
            }
        } else if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            // You could get the SwingWorker and use getProgress, but I'm lazy... 
            pb.setIndeterminate(false);
            pb.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
});
worker.execute();
```

This means you could do this for ANY `SwingWorker`, so long as it was the worker was calling `setProgress` internally...

```
public static class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker {

    public static final int MAX = 1000;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX; index++) {
            Thread.sleep(250);
            setProgress(Math.round((index / (float)MAX) * 100f));
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The benefit of this is that the `PropertyChange` event notification is called from within the context of the of Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI from within.

And fully runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SwingWorkerProgressExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingWorkerProgressExample();
    }

    public SwingWorkerProgressExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar pb;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            pb = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
            pb.setIndeterminate(true);
            add(pb);

            ProgressWorker worker = new ProgressWorker();
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("state".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker) evt.getSource();
                        switch (worker.getState()) {
                            case DONE:
                                // Clean up here...
                                break;
                        }
                    } else if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        // You could get the SwingWorker and use getProgress, but I'm lazy... 
                        System.out.println(EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
                        pb.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pb.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });
            worker.execute();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker {

        public static final int MAX = 1000;

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int index = 0; index < MAX; index++) {
                Thread.sleep(250);
                setProgress(Math.round((index / (float) MAX) * 100f));
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is really useful! I forgot to mention that actual updates to the progress bar are done via a ContainerListener, but if I understand this correctly this code has the worker doing it itself, which is probably a better approach.

Comment: Well, the worker, in this example, is calculating the progress, which triggers a property change event, which is then allowing the `TestPane` to update it's progress bar...trying to keep it decoupled :P

Comment: whoa! okay. finally had time to sit and study your answer. I had not seen `PropertyChangeListener`s before. Was kind of confused (and still am until I try it) of the different strings that return from `Event.getPropertyName`. FYI i am using a Jersey `ContainerListener` to monitor the progress, as it handles HTTP uploads. the OP reflected the final step where the bar is 'cleaned up' as you mention.

Comment: I also like the fact that you've left it 'decoupled'. my boss had suggested overriding `process` but i suspect she will be happier with this.